# controller navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem changes color in IOS7

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have an image that is assigned to the navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem on IOS7. When I get it from the designer it looks fine on the navigation bar's background. But when I implement it in IOS7 it becomes pale and almost disappears.

This is how it's being set up:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[barButtonItemClass alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_menu_icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showLeft:)];
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
```

This is how it should look (image came from my designer):

[image]

And this is how it looks when implemented (on the simulator or a phone):

[image]

What's the solution?

Comment: do you set the tint color for it .?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the tint color of the navigation bar to tint all items in the bar.

A nice solution is to use the `UIAppearance`protocol introduced in iOS 5.
In you AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method put the following code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Note, I am currently not able to try the code.

Cheers!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me :

```
 UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:backButtonImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backBtnAction)];
    customItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -10, 0, 0);// For adjusting the image
    [customItem setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:+3.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];// Hide the Default back button before set custom
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: customItem];
```

Hopefully, causes might be with the `Tint`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may help you ;

// Solve your frame issue.

```
UIImage * bgImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_menu_icon.png"];
UIButton *leftButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, bgImg.size.width, bgImg.size.width)];
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
```

Also change the tintColour to clear colour.